# What's the simplest way to build a binary RPM from a source code checkout with a .spec file

Tags: compiling, rpm

I have a checkout of a source code tree (https://github.com/hautreux/slurm-spank-x11, for the curious) that contains a `.spec` file for building a RPM package. My question is, what's the simplest way of building the binary RPM from that source tree? In the Debian world, I would just run `debian/rules binary` from inside the source tree. Is there an equivalent that's close to being this easy in the RPM world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `rpmbuild`.

`rpmbuild <spec file>` is the RPM equivalent of `fakeroot debian/rules binary`.

**Fedora**

Before your first build, you need to prepare your build system once by installing the Development Tools group:

```
# yum install @development-tools
```

then:

```
# yum install fedora-packager
```

As a user (never as root) create your build environment:

```
$ rpmdev-setuptree
```

This creates a directory tree:

```
~/rpmbuild
       ├── BUILD
       ├── BUILDROOT
       ├── RPMS
       ├── SOURCES
       ├── SPECS
       └── SRPMS
```

To build:

Your `spec` file goes in the `SPECS` directory and your sources in `SOURCES`.

You then change to the `SPECS` directory and run `rpmbuild <spec file>`.

Of course, there is much more to it than the above.  Details are available on the [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package)

**RedHat or CentOS**

The same tool (`rpmbuild`) is used on these distros, but the process and required pacakges are slightly different.  Details for CentOS are on the [CentOS Wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment).

**Copr Service**

This is a build service provided by Fedora that allows you to upload source RPM (`srpm`) files and let the service build it for any target (eg RedHat/CentOS or Fedora). You still need to package the source and the `spec` file, but it saves you installing all the build tools and required dev libraries on your local system.

Comment: So, there's no way to build a RPM without creating all that and manually moving the pieces (sources and `.spec` file) into the right places, correct?

Comment: It's not as difficult as it looks! The other way is to use a service such as `Coppr` - I've added a paragraph.

Comment: Sure. It still is a lot of extra steps for something that in my mind looked pretty self-contained (source tree with `.spec` file). If you want add a sentence saying that this is the simplest way (as far as you know), I'll accept the answer. (After all, the question was about the simplest way.)

Comment: Once your system is prepared, all you do is move src files to `SOURCES` and the spec file to `SPECS` and run `rpmbuild <spec file>.  The main difference is splitting the two files into their respective directories. Other than that, it's quite similar (caveat - I say that with no experience of Debian builds though).